# jQuery button with timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a delete button to delete a photo. The first click animates a `div` on top with the message: "Click again if you really want delete this photo." A second click deletes the photo. If you don't click again in 3sec since the first click, the message will disappear. But then if it disappears and you click the button again, it will still be deleted. I need to stop the script when message disapper to stop post `$.ajax()`

```
$(".delete").toggle(function(){
    $("#top").html("Click again if you really want delete this photo.");
    $("#top").animate({top: "0"}).delay(3000).animate({top: "-50"});
    return false;
}, function() {
    $("#top").animate({top: "-50px"});
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
           ...
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just put a variable in the closure like this:

```
var allowDel;
$(".delete").toggle(function(){
    allowDel = true;
    $("#top").html("Click again if you really want delete this photo.");
    $("#top").animate({top: "0"}).delay(3000).animate({top: "-50"});
    setTimeout(function() { allowDel = false; }, 3000);
    return false;
}, function(){
    if (!allowDel) return;
    $("#top").animate({top: "-50px"});
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
           ...
        });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this (untested):

```
$(".delete").click(function()
{
    if ($(this).attr('canDelete') == 'y')
    {
        $("#top").animate({top: "-50px"});
        ... do delete
    }
    else
    {
        $("#top").html("Click again if you really want delete this photo.");
        $("#top").attr('canDelete', 'y')
                 .animate({top: "0"})
                 .delay(3000)
                 .attr('canDelete', 'n')
                 .animate({top: "-50"});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not do something like this?

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass("confirm") ) {

        //When the button is clicked again within 3 seconds it will have
        //the confirm class and will go here

    } else {

        //The button will go here when clicked first time, a class
        //of confirm is added for 3 seconds.
        $(this).addClass("confirm");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("confirm");
        }, 3000);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, this time without any additional variables OR attributes/properties (not that there is any significant advantage, maybe a tad cleaner). This one uses the message DIV's Y coordinate to determine whether to allow deletion.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Eu2vu/

**Code:**

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
    var top = $('#top');
    if (top.position().top >= 0) {
        top.animate({top: "-50px"});
        console.log('do delete');
    }
    else {
        top.html("Click again if you really want delete this photo.");
        top.animate({top: "0"}).delay(3000).animate({top: "-50"});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So i edit it and it works

```
var allowDel;
$(".delete").click(function(){
   if(allowDel){
       $.ajax();
       allowDel = false;
   }else{
       allowDel = true;
       setTimeout(function() {
           $("#top").slideUp();
       }, 3000);
       return false;
   }
});
```